# Как вывести содержимое папки в json формате?

Tags: php, json, yii2

--
У меня есть папка, в ней есть картинки. Вытащить с помощью php получается, но получить json-формат почему-то не получается.

Делаю это на Yii2.

Вот контроллер:

```
public function actionImage($id) 
{
    $dir = 'gallery/'.$id.'/';
    $files = Scripts::getArrayImages($dir);
    \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON; 
    //\Yii::$app->response->data = $files;
    return $files;
}
```

Вот рабочая функция которая получает данные папки и обрабатывает их:

```
public function getArrayImages($params)
{
    if(Scripts::getCountImage($params) == '') {

    }
    else {
        $filesa = array_diff( scandir( $params), array('..', '.'));
        $files = [];
        foreach($filesa AS $i => $filename) {
            printf(
                Scripts::site().'/'.$params.'%s",',
                urlencode( $filename), $filename
            );
        }             
    } return $files;
}
```

В представлении ничего нет, вьюшка пустая.

Стандартный лэйаут, как в репозитории github Yii2 Advanced.

Данные выводятся, но с ошибкой:

> An Error occurred while handling another error:
>   yii\web\HeadersAlreadySentException: Headers already sent in [...path]

Ругается на содержимое функции:

```
     ...
 Scripts::site().'/'.$params.'%s",',
 ...
```

То есть ошибка вылезает на то что работает и выводится.
Получить данные нужно в json формате. Не в json выводит данные без ошибок.

Что не так? Кто знает решение? Заранее благодарю за отзывчивость и помощь.

Comment: Попробуйте убрать вывод в функции getArrayImages() - вызов `printf()`.

Comment: Описание ошибки говорит о том, что в файле `[...path]` уже был произведён вывод какой-либо информации. Не знаком с Yii, но предполагаю, что `\yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;` выводит заголовок HTTP, а как известно, перед выводом заголовка не должно быть вывода чего-либо, т.е. заголовок должен быть первым.

Comment: `\yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;` - выводит json заголовок MIME тип application/json

то есть если поместить массив по типу:

`['str' => '1', 'word' => 'test', 'bool' => false]`

Мы получим:

`{"str": "1","word": "test","bool": false}`

Очевидно мне надо эксплоидить и имплойдить полученные данные в виде массива, а потом передать на съедение респонсу FORMAT_JSON